# Why is my recursive binary search only finding some matches not all of them? (Java)

Tags: java, binary-search

I'm trying to search through an array of DrillingRecord objects where each object contains an array within itself. I have to find a value at a specific index in the internal array for each object, and then output the array as well as keep track of matches. The search is partially working as it will find some values but not all of them.

```
//record is empty. I put it there so I wouldn't have to call it every time.

    public String binarySearch( int index, int first,  int last, double key, int amount, DrillingRecord record) {
        if (last >= first) {
            int mid = first + (last - first) / 2;
            if (mid < count) { //count is size of the array of objects, data[]
                for (int j = 0; j <= mid; j++) {
                    record = (DrillingRecord) data[j];  //Object[] array hence the cast
                    double[] dataRecord = record.getNums(); //getNums returns array of doubles
                    if (dataRecord[index-2] == key) { //index-2 is not the problem
                        amount++;                        
                        System.out.println(record.noErrors()); // noErrors is basically toString
                    }
                }
                record = (DrillingRecord) data[mid];
                double[] dataRecord = record.getNums();
                if (dataRecord[index-2] < key ) {
                    return binarySearch(index, first, mid+1, key, amount, record);
                } else if (dataRecord[index-2] > key) {
                    return binarySearch(index, mid-1, last, key, amount, record);
                }
            }
            }
        if (amount == 0) {
            return "-1 /n Drilling records found: " + amount;
        }
        return "Drilling records found: " + amount;
    }
```

For example, I know there are 4 records with a value of 12.0 at index 3, but when I run the program it says it only found 2. I've been troubleshooting this for a while, and I suspect it has something to do with the for loop I'm just not quite sure what that is.

Thank you for any help it's much appreciated.

Comment: Are your data sorted?  You can't use binary search on unsorted data.

Comment: @user16632363 yes it is sorted but should I call the sort with every iteration?

Comment: No.  If it's sorted, it's sorted.  It's not going to spontaneously unsort itself.